# redirect an output of program with argument to the file

Tags: c++, redirect, count

I run a

> $ myprogram.exe

which main function signature is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
The program gets one argument as a directory path, and makes some processing to the files in it.
During the processing it prints some results to stdout (or stderr).
I wanted to redirect these results to the file. So I run my program as follow:

> $ myprogram.exe C:\dir > res.txt

The results are still printed to the screen and `res.txt` remains empty.
How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Superficially, it appears your program writes to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  At least on Unix, the `>` notation only redirects `stdout`.  Which shell are you using on Windows?  `cmd.exe` or something else?  It matters because the redirection of `stderr` is different depending on which shell you're using.  In a Bourne/Korn/Bash shell, you'd use `> res.txt 2>&1` to get both `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file, or `>res.txt 2>res.err` for two separate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program probably prints results to *standard error stream* (`stderr`), rather than *standard output stream* (`stdout`).

To redirect `stderr`, (which is file descriptor `2`), use

```
myprogram.exe C:\dir 2> res.txt
```

If you want to redirect *both* `stdout` and `stderr`, you should redirect them to different files, like

```
myprogram.exe C:\dir > res.txt 2> errors.txt
```

or redirect one stream to the other and redirect latter to file

```
myprogram.exe C:\dir >res.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes. At least on Windows 7. `cmd` is not so dumb, as people used to think.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that ">" operator reirects stdout to the output screen, not the stderr, for redirecting stderr you need to write 2>res.txt too , so it should be 1>res.txt 2>res.txt, 
I did not try it so it could give error because of redirection to same file, So more safer approach would be:
 1>res.txt 2>&1

Comment: Well, this will not work, because command processor will want to open same file for writing twice from `stdout` and `stderr` and fail.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I did not thought about that, I only wanted to point out that stderr also needs to be redirected, Thanks for pointing out the error, I will note it :) and +1 vote for your answer .

Answer (score 1):

Send your arguments correctly, If you want to send both `stdout` and `stderr` to file use:

> $ myprogram.exe "C:\dir" > rest.txt 2>&1

you can use number of file descriptor  which you want to redirect before the `>` sign. when we  use `2>&1`, the file descriptor `TWO` ( `stderr` ) is redirected to file descriptor `ONE`, which make `stderr` output result shown as the `stdout`.

Comment: And this will not work, because you should redirect stdout to file and then stderr to stdout

Comment: you are right,need to use `$myprogram.exe "C:\dir" > rest.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is being asked with the C++ tag, here is how can redirect the output to `std::cout` and `std::cerr` from within the program (it is a bit of a hack in that the code leaks a pointer to a `std::filebuf` but this can be prevented if necessary):

```
int main() {
    std::filebuf* fb = new std::filebuf;
    fb->open("res.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    std::cout.rdbuf(fb);
    std::clog.rdbuf(fb);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(fb);
    ...
}
```

Of course, this only works with output written to the standard C++ stream objects, i.e., it won't redirect output sent to `stdout` or `stderr`.